# Play sound and animation

Tags: ios, animation, audio

I have an animation that when a button is pressed it plays.

I need to play a sound at the same time.

If the button was pressed twice in quick succession, the sound would play then start from the beginning on the second press, but the animation would only cycle once as the sound is shorter than the animation length.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Perhaps a way to make the button for sound only work again once the animation has finished playing?

```
//Panel 1 Sound Button Action.
- (IBAction)playSound:(id)sender {
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);


//Panel 1 Sound
    NSURL *buttonURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"panel01" ofType:@"wav"]];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)buttonURL, &SoundID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have the button trigger a single action that both starts the sound playing and begins the animation.

If you want the sound to start playing instantly, load your sound player in your view controllers' viewDidLoad method, and also call prepareToPlay. That will do all the prep-work to get your sound ready to play quickly.

Have the action method set the button to enabled=NO so the user can't click it twice. Use an animation method (like animateWithDuration:animations:completion) that includes a completion block. In the completion block, set enabled=true again. Also call your sound's prepareToPlay method again in the completion block, to get it ready to play again.

Comment: I appreciate this answer so much! Please could you provide an example of the code for your above answer? I bet it's exactly what I need!  It's just a lot to take in when it's written. Thanks Duncan.

Comment: Ok so, the sound playing when I want isn't an issue anymore, I just need to make it so the sound won't play again until the animation has finished and the button pressed again, I am familiar with the button enable code and in fact I have used that within this app for something else, I just don't quite understand completion block code, please could you include an example of that? Thanks

Comment: Post your animation code and I'll give you some pointers on how to modify it.

Comment: Thanks! This code looks great, I will try it soon. I will also update question with animation code.

Answer (score 0):

I can't post code in a comment, so I'm starting another answer. Your button action method might look something like this:

```
-(void) buttonPressed: (UIButton *) button;
{
  //Play the sound here.
  [UIView animateWithDuration: .5
    animations: 
    ^{
      button.enabled = NO; //Disable the button while the animation is running
      //Your animation code goes here
    }
    completion: 
    ^{
      button.enabled = YES;  //Re-enable the button once the animation is finished.
    }
  ];
}
```